# Compare two json objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, xml

suppose to have 2 json object like this :

```
 var obj1=    {
"errors":{
  "addcreditcard":"Non è stato possibile associare questa carta, ti preghiamo di ricontrollare i dati e riprovare.",
  "creditrecharge":"Si è verificato un errore durante la ricarica.",
  "ticketvalidation":"Siamo spiacenti, si è verificato un problema durante la validazione.",
  "ticketpurchase": "Siamo spiacenti, si è verificato un problema durante l\"acquisto.",
  "qrwrong": "Hai scansionato un QR Code non valido. Scansiona un QR Code OpenMove."
 }
}
```

And this :

```
var obj2 =  {
'errors':{
   'addcreditcard':'Wir konnten diese Karte nicht verifizieren. Bitte         \u00fcberpr\u00fcfe deine Angaben und versuche es noch einmal.',
   'creditrecharge':'Beim Aufladen deines Guthabens ist ein Fehler aufgetreten.',
   'qrwrong': 'Sie haben einen ung\u00fcltigen QR Code gescannt. Bitte einen OpenMove QR Code scannen.'
}
}
```

How can I get another object (using javascript or jquery) with the values in the first json but not in the second?
In this case it will be :

```
 var example = {
  "errors":{
      "ticketvalidation":"Siamo spiacenti, si è verificato un problema durante  la validazione.",
     "ticketpurchase": "Siamo spiacenti, si è verificato un problema durante l\"acquisto."
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code that iterates over all properties in the second object and checks if they exist in the first one:

```
   var obj1=    {
"errors":{
  "addcreditcard":"Non è stato possibile associare questa carta, ti preghiamo di ricontrollare i dati e riprovare.",
  "creditrecharge":"Si è verificato un errore durante la ricarica.",
  "ticketvalidation":"Siamo spiacenti, si è verificato un problema durante la validazione.",
  "ticketpurchase": "Siamo spiacenti, si è verificato un problema durante l\"acquisto.",
  "qrwrong": "Hai scansionato un QR Code non valido. Scansiona un QR Code OpenMove."
 }
};

 var obj2 =  {
'errors':{
   'addcreditcard':'Wir konnten diese Karte nicht verifizieren. Bitte         \u00fcberpr\u00fcfe deine Angaben und versuche es noch einmal.',
   'creditrecharge':'Beim Aufladen deines Guthabens ist ein Fehler aufgetreten.',
   'qrwrong': 'Sie haben einen ung\u00fcltigen QR Code gescannt. Bitte einen OpenMove QR Code scannen.'
}
};

var finalObject = {};
for (var property in obj1.errors) {

    if (obj1.errors.hasOwnProperty(property)) {

       if(!obj2.errors.hasOwnProperty(property)){

           // exist only in first
           finalObject[property] = obj1.errors[property];
       }
    }
}

console.log(finalObject)
```

Comment: Thanks, now I'm having trouble converting text to an Ajax call to json object. Anyway I think it's fair:)

Comment: I fix it You have [here](http://jsbin.com/rofuziqotu/edit?js,console) a working fiddle.

Comment: Thanks very much, but there is no way to get to do it dynamically ? Without putting the " .ticket "

Comment: If you want two levels, code will be complex. Here i suppose your main object is "error"

Comment: OK thanks . It would be better if it did dynamically because I have to compare many json all different but I will find a way :)